# Why is the subgroup generated by a subset $U$ defined as the set of *finite* combinations of elements of $U$? Why discard the infinite ones?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

From Wikipedia:

> a generating set of a group is a subset such that every element of the group can be expressed as a combination (under the group operation) of finitely many elements of the subset and their inverses.

I'm confused because there are examples of combinations of infinitely many elements of a subset which converge to an element that cannot be represented as a finite combination, and I feel like that element *should* be in the generated subgroup. Why shouldn't it?

As an example of what I mean, take $(\Bbb R, +)$ and its subset $\{\frac 1{n!} \mid n \in \Bbb N \}$. Why shouldn't $e$ be in the generated subgroup?

Comment: the rules specify "finite combinations".  Infinite sums don't have much  meaning in a general group.  $e$ is not rational so it can't be obtained as a finite sum of rationals.

Comment: How would you define an infinite product (or sum in the abelian case) abstractly? You are not always in a metric space or more generally a topological space where you can consider notions like convergence. If you take an arbitrary set together with an operation you just get finite combinations. This is all that makes sense without having more structure.

Comment: You would need to involve topology to make sense of this. For instance $e$ would be in the closed subgroup generated by your subset.

Comment: @ThorWittich I thought that $e$ should really be in the generated subgroup $Û$ because $e=\sum_0^{+\infty} 1/n!$ and each partial sum is in $Û$, so this countably infinite sum should be too. It is certainly a real number. It feels like the closure of $Û$ implies this. Why should that sum be undefined?

Comment: It is defined, but not in the realm of groups. It exists in the realm of topological groups.

Comment: @CaptainLama I feel like I can talk about a countably infinite iteration of the group operation without defining it, in this case, because it is already defined in $\Bbb R$. Like isn't the group $(\Bbb R, +)$ automatically a topological group, by virtue of the properties of $\Bbb R$? Can we even define $\Bbb R$ without the least upper bound property?

Comment: @TheFootprint: As an abstract group, the additive group of real numbers is $\oplus_{\alpha\in A} {\mathbb Q}$, where $A$ has the cardinality of continuum (abstractly defined as the set of all subsets of ${\mathbb N}$).

Comment: A group itself consists only of finite products of elements. People do study something resembling the set of infinite products of discrete groups (that is, groups without topology), which is the "boundary" of the group. In certain cases, the boundary is invariant of the group (as in, changing generating set does not alter the boundary). I don't know if this is always true though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two reasons the group generated by $U$ is defined as the set of finite products, which I will denote by $\Pi(U)$:

1.)  The group generated by $U$ is usually taken to be the *smallest* group containing $U$; it is evident the set $\Pi(U)$ satisfies this criterion, since it is clearly closed under the group operation (finite products of finite products of elements of $U$ are, after all, themselves *finite products* of elements of $U$) and the taking of inverses, and contains the identity element $e$ since

$e = xx^{-1}, \; x \in  U; \tag 1$

thus $\Pi(U)$ is a group; and any group containing $U$ must contain $\Pi(U)$ if it is to be closed under the group operation and inversation.  Indeed, $\Pi(U)$ is often though of as he intersection of all groups containing $U$; in this sense it *is* the smallest group containing $U$.

2.)  We really can't define *infinite products* of elements of $U$ anyway, in a *purely algebraic* sense; to do so generally requires some notion of $convergence$ of a sequence of products such as

$x_1x_2, x_1x_2x_3, x_1x_2x_3x_4, \ldots; \tag 2$

but convergence lies in the realm of *topology*, so we would have to adopt some appropriate topological structure to give meaning to such *infinite products*.

Well, there are two of my main reasons for accepting the definition of the group generated by $U$ as $\Pi(U)$.  The comment stream attached to the question itself contains more useful insights, cf. the remarks of ThorWitch and Captain Lama.

Comment: I thought that, in my example, the topology is "inherited" naturally from the topology of $\Bbb R$, so that the infinite series which converges to $e$ is defined and is in the generated subgroup because each partial sum is in the generated subgroup, and therefore every subgroup which contains $U$ also contains $e$. But I see now that this is not so; it just follows from the definition of *closure* of a group, which is intrinsically finite. Is it correct? This, combined with your argument of "smallest subgroup" makes perfect sense. Thank you

Comment: So it is not that the infinite series is not defined, it's just that it wouldn't be the *smallest* subgroup.

Comment: @TheFootprint:  it strikes me that you are asking the right questions.  It is a subtle issue with $\Bbb R$, since it is usually constructed by using order properties of $\Bbb Q$, and this is damn close to topology.

Comment: @TheFootprint:  I think your comments express the right idea!  Cheers!